# How to Content Group and Count based on URL alone in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Say, these 5 urls are hit for my website(From a mobile device):
http://example.com/a?user=abcd&page=123
http://example.com/a?user=efgh&page=456
http://example.com/a?user=abcd&page=456
http://example.com/a?user=abcd&page=456 (Exactly same as above)
http://example.com/a?user=efgh&page=789

Now, what I need is something like:
page 123, users: 1
page 456, users: 2
page 789, users: 1

Is it possible to query Google Analytics for the above?
Or, is there any other solution based on mobile devices, as the urls are hit from them?